# Loop and select results for each row

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to loop over results in query and then for each item insert id into temp_table. I've written the query:

```
    BEGIN
    FOR item IN
    (SELECT ID FROM INV_SRV1 WHERE SRV_CATEGORY_ID IN 
                (
                    SELECT id
                    FROM   inv_srv_category1
                    START WITH parent_category_id = 1
                    CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_category_id
                ) OR SRV_CATEGORY_ID = 1)
    LOOP
INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE (ID)
    (SELECT s.id
        FROM   inv_srv1 s
        START WITH s.parent_srv_id = item.id
        CONNECT BY PRIOR item.id = s.parent_srv_id);
    END LOOP;
    END;
```

Expected result (SELECT ID FROM TEMP_TABLE):

```
+----+
| ID |
+----+
| 1  |
+----+
| 2  |
+----+
| 3  |
+----+
| 4  |
+----+
| 5  |
+----+
| 6  |
+----+
| 7  |
+----+
| 8  |
+----+
| 9  |
+----+
| 10 |
+----+
| 11 |
+----+
| 12 |
+----+
| 13 |
+----+
| 14 |
+----+
| 15 |
+----+
| 16 |
+----+
| 17 |
+----+
| 18 |
+----+
| 19 |
+----+
```

but it's giving me error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 11, column 2:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
   date <a string literal with character set specification>
   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
   <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
   <an alternat
ORA-06550: line 14, column 47:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * @ % & - + ; / at for mod remainder rem
   <an exponent (**)> and or group having intersect minus order
   start union where connect || multiset
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Any idea how could I run this?

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE
(
ID NUMBER
)

CREATE TABLE INV_SRV_CATEGORY1
(
    ID number,
    name nvarchar2(255),
    PARENT_CATEGORY_ID number
)

insert into inv_srv_category1(id, name, parent_category_id)
select 1, 'deveti', null from dual
union all select 2, 'deseti', 1 from dual
union all select 3, 'enajsti', 1 from dual
union all select 4, 'dvanajsti', 1 from dual
union all select 5, 'trinajsti', 1 from dual

union all select 6, 'deseti', 2 from SYS.dual
union all select 7, 'enajsti', 2 from dual
union all select 8, 'dvanajsti', 6 from dual
union all select 9, 'trinajsti', 4 from dual

union all select 10, 'deseti', 9 from SYS.dual
union all select 11, 'enajsti', 9 from dual
union all select 12, 'dvanajsti', 11 from dual
union all select 13, 'trinajsti', 12 from dual


CREATE TABLE INV_SRV1
(
    ID number,
    name nvarchar2(255),
    SRV_CATEGORY_ID number,
    PARENT_SRV_ID number
)

insert into inv_srv1(id, name, srv_category_id, parent_srv_id)
select 1, 'under root 1', 1, null from dual
union all select 2, 'under root 1', 1, null from dual
union all select 3, 'under root 1', 1, null from dual
union all select 4, 'under root 1', 1, null from dual

union all select 5, 'under srv 4', null, 4 from dual
union all select 6, 'under srv 4', null, 4 from dual
union all select 7, 'under srv 4', null, 4 from dual

union all select 8, 'under srv 7', null, 7 from dual
union all select 9, 'under srv 7', null, 7 from dual
union all select 10, 'under srv 7', null, 7 from dual

union all select 11, 'under cat 7', 7, null from dual
union all select 12, 'under cat 7', 7, null from dual

union all select 13, 'under srv 11', null, 11 from dual
union all select 14, 'under srv 11', null, 11 from dual

union all select 15, 'under srv 11', 5, null from dual
union all select 16, 'under srv 11', 5, null from dual

union all select 17, 'under cat 13', 13, null from dual
union all select 18, 'under cat 13', 13, null from dual
union all select 19, 'under srv 18', null, 18 from dual
```

Comment: Please show us the results that you expect for this sample data, as tabular text.

Comment: OK, question updated.

Comment: @GMB - I've slightly changed question - I would like to insert into temp_table for each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *how* (meaning: so that it doesn't fail). But, does it return what you want? You should know.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2     for item
  3        in (select id
  4              from inv_srv1
  5             where    srv_category_id in (    select id
  6                                                from inv_srv_category1
  7                                          start with parent_category_id = 1
  8                                          connect by prior id =
  9                                                        parent_category_id)
 10                   or srv_category_id = 1)
 11     loop
 12       for chi in (select s.id
 13                   from inv_srv1 s
 14                   start with s.parent_srv_id = item.id
 15                   connect by nocycle prior item.id = s.parent_srv_id
 16                  )
 17       loop
 18          dbms_output.put_line(item.id ||' - '|| chi.id);
 19       end loop;
 20     end loop;
 21  end;
 22  /
4 - 5
4 - 6
4 - 7
11 - 13
11 - 14
18 - 19

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Your answer is great :) Is it possible somehow to insert each of the rows into table? So, instead of dbms_output.put_line there is insert statement? Because I need to use this results further, after query ends.

Comment: Sure; just replace DBMS_OUTPUT call with INSERT INTO statement.